# How to use JCache in Scala? I get compiler type error: found String required K

Tags: java, scala, memcached

I'm learning [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) and trying to use javax.cache in Scala code and can't find how to solve this problem:

```
val cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance.getCacheFactory
val map = new HashMap
val cache = cacheFactory.createCache(map)

def rawSet(key:String, value:Array[Byte]) {
    cache.put(key, value)
}
```

and the compiler error is:

> error: type mismatch
>   found: String
>   required: K
>   in cache.put(key, value)

**Edit:**
As Daniel said, I should have mentioned in the question that I'm over app engine since that seems to be highly relevant. In this case, the solution is to create a small class in Java to do this particular code, and call it from Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
val cache: Cache[_, AnyRef] = cacheFactory.getCache(new HashMap[String, AnyRef])
```

Or even `Cache[_, _]`. You may have to use something like this to put the values:

```
cache.asInstanceOf[HashMap[String,AnyRef]].put(key, value)
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it without `asInstanceOf`, using the full existential syntax (`Cache[T, AnyRef] forSome { type T }`), but I can't recall how (or find the site that explains it :).

Comment: No luck, I cant use asInstanceOf, I get this at runtime:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.stdimpl.GCache cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
(I'm over app engine)

Comment: If you are over app engine, you should have mentioned that in the question, as that is highly relevant. In that case, you should create a small class in Java to do this particular code, and call it from Scala.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, I thought that app engine implementation of jcache was totally compatible. I also thought that *any* java code could be used from scala.

Comment: Any Java code can be used from Scala. It is App Engine who is having trouble with the code produced by Scala (specifically, asInstanceOf).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be one of providing the correct generic parameters for the `HashMap`. I presume you want something like:

```
val map = new HashMap[String, AnyRef]
```

Remember: **Scala does not allow the use of raw types**.

It's probably a good idea to use the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) to see what type Scala has inferred your `cache` variable to be, or to provide the type information yourself to see whether it compiles OK:

```
val cache: Cache[String, AnyRef] = cacheFactory.getCache(map)
```

Comment: Not solved, using:  
val cache: Cache[String, AnyRef] = cacheFactory.getCache(new HashMap[String, AnyRef])

I get the same compiler error as before: found: String, required: K

Comment: It looks as though the `javax.cache` library (as documented here: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/jsr107/javax.cache.htm) badly misuses generics in *mixing parameterized and raw types*. To be honest, I'm not sure what scala would do with this (raw types are illegal in scala, as I've said). Perhaps this is out-of-date documentation?

Comment: Can you attempt to use the **REPL** as requested? Just print out the results of `CacheManager.getInstance.getCacheFactory` - this should give you the type parameters of your cache instance

Comment: I have no experience using scala interpreter, I'm trying javax.cache.CacheManager.getInstance.getCacheFactory but I get error "value cache is not a member of package javax"

Comment: @Damian - my guess is that you are not running the console with the right JAR files on the classpath. Daniel's suggestion below of using `cache.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]]` is possibly what you need to do